# Why does this oscillator not work with a voltage less than 9 V?

Tags: oscillator, feedback, stability, distortion, soft-starter

By chance of my research and simulations and various tests, I found the diagram of an oscillator with strange behavior. All the oscillators (quasi) that I have encountered work whatever the supply voltage is (in principle within the limits generally accepted by the electrical characteristics.) I know some will be using it.

What I have found (with difficulties,  after changing values) is that this one only works above about 9 V (as drawn.)

Characteristics are:

- Distortionless with good performance
- high level output
- soft starting within few periods ( < 10)

With "pulsing" supply, can be used as signal generator "percussion" (disappears after some delay. Others

What kind of oscillator is it? Simulator problems or reality? Am I forgetting something?

I did not search yet the reasons of such behavior, I first concentrated getting it working.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the DC operating points of the various nodes at a range of supply voltages?

Comment: Looks interesting and was fun to play with. I immediately removed R1 and replaced your Vcc with an AC probe for doing a Bode plot to look at the collector output from perhaps 100 Hz to 1 MHz. I adjusted the value of your R3 and V1 and saw how it changed. There was only a narrow range of values for R3 for any given setup which results in undistorted oscillations. Smaller R3 values lead towards distorted oscillation and larger R3 values lead to rapidly dampening oscillations.

Comment: @Theodore  - DC-analysys by microp12 operating points seems "good" for 5 V -> 20 V ... BC107 has a Vce max of ~40 V

Comment: @ jonk  - I noted that behavior (distortion) when I changed the value of C4-C5 proportionnaly.

Comment: @JRE - Thanks for editing ... I am not really "good" in english :) And "google translate" too :)

Comment: @jonk What simulator are you using?  I built this in CircuitLab exactly as shown in the question, and couldn't get any sustained oscillation at any V1 between 0 V and 40 V: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/c6yv6899g7h2/osc/

Comment: I use microcap v12 FREE from http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: @Theodore I'm using LTspice. And no, I've not built nor have I sat down to spend time analyzing this circuit (as well as I'm sometimes able, anyway.) It has a high-Q spike right at its oscillation frequency.

Comment: New link for microcap v12 https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110